# Flutter Http Multi part Request get response body

Tags: flutter, http, multipartfile

I want to get response data from `MultipartRequest`
I uploaded an image to service and I should get image URL in response but I got an  `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.`

this My code snippet

```
  //upload image
  Future<ApiResponse> uploadOrderPic(
      {required String orderID,
      required File image,
      required String type}) async {
    ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
    var token = await getToken();
    try {
      var request = http.MultipartRequest(
          "POST", Uri.parse(uploadPicUrl));
      request.files
          .add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', image.path));
      request.fields['id'] = '1084';
      request.fields['type'] = 'invoice';
      request.headers['${HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader}'] = 'Bearer $token';
      request.send().then((value) => http.Response.fromStream(value).then((onValue) {
        try {
          // get response...
          logger.i(value.stream.bytesToString());

        } catch (e) {
          // handle exception
          logger.e(e);// This catch Stream has already been listened to.
        }
      }));
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e(e);
      apiResponse.error = serverError;
    }
    return apiResponse;
  }
```

`the logger.i(value.statusCode);` print status code is 200(ok)
but
`logger.i(value.stream.bytesToString());` print  exception

Comment: use `onValue.body` instead of `value.stream`. As the error suggests, `fromStream` listened to the stream and created a `Response` (which you've called `onValue`) - so use that.

Comment: Also, It would read better if you replaced all those `then` with `await`. `await request.send()`, `await Response.fromStream(stream);`,

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code block to print the final response body:

```
final response = await request.send();
log("${(await http.Response.fromStream(response)).body}");
```